# Formal way of saying "blah blah blah" or "........" to indicate generic filler or omissions in a document when providing examples

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

In my specific case, I'm writing a tutorial on how to format a list of items.  Now I would usually say *etc.* , but in my mind you can only use etc. following a statement, rather than proceeding it.

So I would be happy to when addressing how "thing1", "thing2" and "thing3" should be formatted, say that the finished product should look like:

> {
>  thing1
>  thing2
>  thing3
>  etc. 
>  }

But to my mind, when addressing things 24-26,

> {
>  etc. 
>  thing24
>  thing25
>  thing26
>  etc.
>  }

doesn't seem right.

Is there a short latin word or other more formal convention that fills the gap I'm looking for?  Rather than resorting to:

> {
>  blah blah blah
>  thing24
>  thing25
>  thing26
>  etc.
>   }

Which isn't that professional.

Of course in many cases it's possible to get around this by just not giving such an example, but this is interesting to me as a general question as well as to solve a specific problem.

Comment: why not use the symbol for ellipsis . . . ?

Comment: I will if I can't find a better alternative.  It looks a bit ugly in the context I'm using it, and I'm wording if there's a word I can use

Comment: Well you could use *et alia* (Latin for *and others*) or *et al.* in brackets, [et al.], but I don't recall having seen it used in this way.

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for an equivalent to 'etc.' or 'and so on' which can be used *before* a list of examples?

Comment: One can use something along the lines of "word word word [omitted text] word word word".  The wording of "omitted text" can hint at the reason for omission.

Comment: You must use the ellipsis. There is no better alternative. There is no worse alternative, either. There's no alternative at all. The ellipsis is what you must use.

Answer (score 3):

In mathematics there are ellipsis in all directions. EL&U doesn't appear to have latex typesetting but the codes are:

> **\dots \vdots \ddots**

An example of \vdots:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to elpisis, you might consider a brief explanation in square brackets.

> *If we highlight multiples of 56 we would see:*
>
> { 
>  [The 54 previous items]
>  Item55 
> Item56*
>  Item57 
> [The subsequent items]
>   }